# Mapping pandas boolean columns to 1,0 TypeError: Invalid value '0' for dtype boolean

Tags: pandas, boolean

Have several boolean columns with NA in a pandas dataframe. Try to map boolean columns to 1/0 for further modeling but got TypeError: Invalid value '0' for dtype boolean

```
bool_cols = ['if_new_user', 'if_weekend','if_holiday']
df[bool_cols] = df[bool_cols].astype('boolean')
df[bool_cols] = df[bool_cols].replace({False: 0, True: 1})
```

the last line always gave an error

```
TypeError: Invalid value '0' for dtype boolean
```

Tried:

```
df[bool_cols] = df[bool_cols].applymap(lambda x: 1 if x == True else x)
df[bool_cols] = df[bool_cols].applymap(lambda x: 0 if x == False else x)
```

which gives

```
TypeError: boolean value of NA is ambiguous
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to assign back while assigning datatype.

```
df[bool_cols].astype('boolean') # No need to assigning it to df[bool_cols]
```

Try this

```
bool_cols = ['if_new_user', 'if_weekend', 'if_holiday']
df[bool_cols].astype('boolean')
df[bool_cols] = df[bool_cols].replace({
    False: 0,
    True: 1
})
```

Comment: df[bool_cols].astype('boolean') does not cause any problem. It's the last line cause error. Tried this but still got same error.

Answer (score 0):

Before I used following function to map:

```
def map_bool_to_values(data: pd.DataFrame, boolean_cols: list):
    # for each col in boolean_cols replace False: 0, True: 1 and preserve nan.
    for col in boolean_cols:
        data[col] = data[col].astype('boolean')
        data[col].replace({False: 0, True: 1}, inplace=True)
    return data
```

and it worked before.
Not sure if it is because pandas version or some reason it's not working anymore. Current pandas version is '2.0.3'

Finally tried to change bool_cols to str and replace the values.
So far it's working.

```
df[bool_cols]  = df[bool_cols].astype(str)


df[bool_cols]  = df[bool_cols].replace({'False': 0, 'True': 1,'<NA>':'unknow'})
```